# how can I use a different Android sdk and resolution simulator

Tags: trigger.io, forge

How can I use a different Android sdk and resolution simulator with testing use forge?

I have tried to change it within AVD Manager, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a different Android SDK to use with the android.sdk parameter (http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/tools/local-config.html#android)

E.g. on a command-line,

```
forge build --android.sdk /Applications/sdk
```

In your local_config.json:

```
{
  "android": {
    "sdk": "/opt/local/android-sdk"
  }
}
```

To use different AVD levels or otherwise customise the emulator, open the Android SDK manager, then the AVD manager. Create, customise and start whatever AVD you want.

**Note**: you cannot use 2.3 AVDs, due to a bug in the emulator.

Next time you use `forge run android`, we will use that manually started emulator.